# Request binding not working for Kotlin class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a form object:

```
public class UserFormJava {
    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }
    // getter, setter
}
```

And I have a simple controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @PostMapping("")
    public String postForm(@Valid UserForm userForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        System.out.println(userForm + " " + bindingResult);
        return "/users/form";
    }
}
```

It works fine. But binding doesn't work (parameter `userForm` is null`) if I rewrite UserForm in Kotlin like this:

```
open class UserForm(@NotNull
                    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") var dateTime: LocalDateTime? = null)
```

And try to bind it in the Controller the same way:

```
@PostMapping("")
public String postForm(@Valid UserForm userForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    System.out.println(userForm + " " + bindingResult);
    return "/users/form";
}
```

Why binding fails and how to fix it ?

I created [example Github project](https://github.com/alexbezhan/localdatetime-binding-error) for reproduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what was the problem. The issue was actually in several places:
1. To render a form I used the following method:

```
@GetMapping("")
public String userForm(UserForm userForm) {
    userForm.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
    return "/users/form";
}
```

As you can see it sets the current date time to now and uses default `Formatter` under the hood.

Now, on the receiving form submission side, I had specified format:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") var dateTime: LocalDateTime? = null
```

but the correct way to do it is to use `@field:` target like this:

```
@field:DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") var dateTime: LocalDateTime? = null
```

And finally, to fix inconsistency in the formats I just added my custom `Formatter` for `LocalDateTime`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addFormatter(new Formatter<LocalDateTime>() {
            final DateTimeFormatter dtFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

            @Override
            public LocalDateTime parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
                return LocalDateTime.from(dtFormatter.parse(text));
            }

            @Override
            public String print(LocalDateTime object, Locale locale) {
                return dtFormatter.format(object);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add [RequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) annotation on userForm parameter to be bound to the body of the web request. Also the UserForm class in Kotlin has a constructor with parameters that can't be created by JSON deserializer. You can rewrite it with Kotlin data class.

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @PostMapping("")
    public String postForm(@Valid @RequestBody UserForm userForm, BindingResult bindingResult){
        System.out.println(userForm + " " + bindingResult);
        return "/users/form";
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Kotlin `UserForm` has empty constructor as well. 2. Why it works with Java and doesn't work with Kotlin ? 3. AFAIK `RequestBody` doesn't work with form submission(content type `x-www-form-urlencoded`)